# Postgres trigger function error

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am trying to write a trigger function in postgress 9.5. But i get an error when trying to execute the script.

My trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE batch (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  batch_type varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  external_id varchar(255),
  status varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT unique_external_id UNIQUE(batch_type,external_id)
);

      CREATE TABLE batch_wip (
      batch_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (batch_id)
    );

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_records_into_batch_wip()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
      IF NEW.status = 'STARTED' THEN
        INSERT INTO batch_wip(batch_id) VALUES(NEW.id);
      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER new_batch_record_inserts
      AFTER INSERT
      ON batch
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_records_into_batch_wip();
```

Error Iam getting,

Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate

Migration V14__add_work_in_progress_table_and_trigger.sql failed

SQL State  : 42001
  Error Code : 42001
  Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION[*] INSERT_RECORDS_INTO_BATCH_WIP()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN

```
IF NEW.STATUS = 'STARTED' THEN
  INSERT INTO BATCH_WIP(BATCH_ID) VALUES(NEW.ID) "; expected "FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:
```

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_records_into_batch_wip()
    RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.status = 'STARTED' THEN
      INSERT INTO batch_wip(batch_id) VALUES(NEW.id) [42001-191]
  Location   : /Users/bla/migration/V14__add_work_in_progress_table_and_trigger.sql (/Users/bla/migration/V14__add_work_in_progress_table_and_trigger.sql)
  Line       : 11
  Statement  : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_records_into_batch_wip()
    RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN

```
IF NEW.status = 'STARTED' THEN
  INSERT INTO batch_wip(batch_id) VALUES(NEW.id)
```

Can someone figure out what wrong with my sql script?

Comment: In the `CREATE TRIGGER`, it says `ON batch`, but there is no such table. Did you paste the example here correctly?

Comment: @redneb, the batch table exists in the database. Anyway, i ll update the question to include batch table ddl

Comment: I've tried it in my machine (also postgress 9.5) and it works. Also, the code looks ok. It's probably some misconfiguration issue.

Comment: It looks like the semicolon on the `INSERT` line is being treated as the end of the statement. I guess the tool you're using to run it is not recognising the `$BODY$` delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, It was other configuration issue. Nothing wrong with the script. Thanks all.